# How can I find which user is accessing a file using strace?

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, strace

My actual problem is that Nginx is not able to render pages (403 forbidden) despite the permissions being set to appropriately (in my opinion)

The directory of stackoverflow at default location:

```
user1@wfe1 ~]$ ls /usr/share/nginx/html/stackoverflow/ -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 23 Mar  9 02:59 .
drwxrwxr-x. 4 root www  89 Mar  9 02:59 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  6 Mar  9 02:59 index.html
```

The directory of stackoverflow at user location:

```
[user1@wfe1 ~]$ ls stackoverflow/ -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root  root  23 Mar  9 02:52 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 nginx nginx 79 Mar  9 02:51 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root   6 Mar  9 02:52 index.html
```

Configuration file:

```
server{
   listen           80;
   server_name localhost;
   root /usr/share/nginx/html/stackoverflow; #Works
   #root /home/user1/stackoverflow;          #Doesn't work
   index index.html;
}
```

The one that fails shows a 403 forbidden error. To get to the root of the issue, 
I am using the following command and browse using my browser which yields the output as shown below...

```
[root@wfe1 user1]# sudo strace -p 9114 -e trace=file
Process 9114 attached
stat("/home/user1/stackoverflow/index.html", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6, ...}) = 0
open("/home/user1/stackoverflow/index.html", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/home/user1/stackoverflow/favicon.ico", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The output as you can see is Permission Denied. I would like to know which user account was used to access the file? How can I dig in further?

---

EDITED the question with newer permissions.

Comment: Does this question come down to "what is the effective user ID of process 26934?", or is using strace in particular important for some outside reason? You can [edit] with more detail from your actual problem, and people may have non-strace solutions to that.

Comment: Knowing an effective user ID should help Michael. I am adding more details to the question.

Comment: To me, it looks like it is due to /home/user1 folder is not accessible.

Comment: I am able to cat the file from the same location.

Comment: @RahulSoni _You_ are able, but _nginx_ is not. The directory `/home/user1` is only readable and executable by user1, not anyone else. Therefore anything under it, whatever its permissions are, can only be accessed by user1.

Comment: @Dubu Thanks! How should I change this?

Comment: @Dubu I tried changing that too (chmod 755) and I still see the same behaviour? Can you please confirm that Nginx works when you drop files in the user directory?

Comment: This sounds like an selinux issue. Take a look at https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-se-linux-changes-upgrading-rhel-6-6/ for some recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is clear in your output:

```
[root@wfe1 user1]# ls -al site3
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nginx nginx   23 Mar  6 06:12 .
drwx------. 5 user1 user1 4096 Mar  6 06:12 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 nginx nginx    6 Mar  6 06:12 index.html
```

The file and the containing directory are both accessible to nginx, but the permissions of the *parent directory* are `drwx------`, and that will block access to that directory and all its children.

You need to check the access privileges for every directory level right up to and including the root.

Comment: Exactly, this is the correct answer.

Comment: I brought that up as a comment, but @RahulSoni claimed that changing permissions on the user dir did not change the behavior.

Comment: @Dubu That would be a different question.

Comment: @ams thanks for trying to help. My actual problem is that Nginx doesn't like it when I store the file any where in the home directory of the user with appropriate permissions. Copying this directory to /html immediately fixes the issue. Please see if you can reproduce this issue and feel free to correct me if I am wrong. I might be missing something.

Comment: To me it looks like the permissions are good. I have redited the question with latest output. It should help you reproduce the issue at your end. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can see a process's current euid By looking at `/proc/PID/status`. If the euid or uid are 0, then check selinix's `audit.log` and POSIX ACL lists on the directory via `getfacl`

Answer (score 0):

You can see current access to the file by using the list open files command,  `lsof`. Below is some example output.

```
# lsof

COMMAND  PID       USER   FD      TYPE     DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
init       1       root  cwd       DIR        8,1      4096          2 /
init       1       root  txt       REG        8,1    124704     917562 /sbin/init
init       1       root    0u      CHR        1,3       0t0       4369 /dev/null
init       1       root    1u      CHR        1,3       0t0       4369 /dev/null
init       1       root    2u      CHR        1,3       0t0       4369 /dev/null
init       1       root    3r     FIFO        0,8       0t0       6323 pipe
```

Example 2 - +D = recursive:

```
# lsof +D /var/log/

COMMAND   PID   USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
rsyslogd  488 syslog   1w   REG    8,1     1151 268940 /var/log/syslog
rsyslogd  488 syslog   2w   REG    8,1     2405 269616 /var/log/auth.log
console-k 144   root   9w   REG    8,1    10871 269369 /var/log/ConsoleKit/history
```

`Man lsof` will give you some additional examples.

Comment: I am afraid this won't work in such situations, since it will only list the files that are currently open. In the issue mentioned, the files are not even opened due to permissions denied.